# Difference between margin and padding?

Tags: css

What exactly is the difference between **margin** and **padding** in CSS? It really doesn't seem to serve much purpose. Could you give me an example of where the differences lie (and why it is important to know the difference)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060456/difference-b-w-padding-and-margin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin First three links from searching `padding vs margin`.  I think we need to add arrows to the search bar and make green.

Comment: This might help you understanding the difference http://www.digizol.com/2006/12/margin-vs-padding-css-properties.html

Comment: Also be aware that Internet Explorer sums the margins/borders/padding widths differently (in default non-quirks mode) than almost all other browsers.

Comment: If margin doesn't work, try padding

Answer (score 436):

`padding` is the space between the content and the `border`, whereas `margin` is the space outside the border. Here's an image I found from a quick Google search, that illustrates this idea.

[image]

Comment: Also check out these sites for a definition.  But the graphic is a perfect illustration.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Comment: @maclunian: Also check out this site http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp in addition to @Suroot's links above.

Comment: How does this relate to the set Width and Height of the content though? Where is that measured on all this?

Answer (score 143):

One key thing that is missing in the answers here:

**Top/Bottom margins are collapsible.**

So if you have a 20px margin at the bottom of an element and a 30px margin at the top of the next element, the margin between the two elements will be 30px rather than 50px. This does not apply to left/right margin or padding.

Comment: Note that there are very specific circumstances in which vertical margins collapse - not just any two vertical margins will do so. Which just makes it all the more confusing (unless you're *very* familiar with the box model).

Answer (score 90):

Margin is applied to the **outside** of your element hence affecting how far your element is away from other elements.

Padding is applied to the **inside** of your element hence affecting how far your element's content is away from the border.

Also, using margin will not affect your element's dimensions whereas padding will make your elements dimensions (set height + padding) so for example if you have a 100x100px div with a 5px padding, your div will actually be 105x105px

Comment: I believe padding is applied to every side, so the element would be 110x110px

Comment: Ehm, afaik padding doesn't change your element's width if that width has been set to anything other than `auto`. If the width is `auto`, then additional padding will increase the padded element's width accordingly (and from both sides, as @2013Asker mentioned)

Comment: I think its a bit misleading to say that you div will be 110px by 110px because the width of your div will still be 100px (assuming box-sizing is set as content-box).

Answer (score 49):

Remember these 3 points:

- The Margin is the extra space **around** the control.
- The Padding is extra space **inside** the control.
- The Padding of **an outer control is the Margin of an inner control**.

Demo Image:(where red box is desire control)
[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer why it is important to know the difference.

Answer (score 42):

The simplest defenition is ;
padding is a space given inside the border of the container element and margin is given outside.
For an element which is not a container, padding may not make much sense, but margin defenitly will help to arrange it.

Answer (score 30):

Padding is space *inside* the border, whereas Margin is space *outside* the border.

Answer (score 25):

**Padding**

Padding is a CSS property that defines the space between an element content and its border (if it has a border). If an element has a border around it, padding will give space from that border to the element content which appears in that border. If an element does not have a border around it, then adding padding has no effect at all on that element, because there is no border to give space from.

**Margin**

Margin is a CSS property that defines the space of outside of an element to its next outside element.

Margin affects elements that both have or do not have borders. If an element has a border, margin defines the space from this border to the next outer element. If an element does not have a border, then margin defines the space from the element content to the next outer element.

**Difference Between Padding and Margin**

So the difference between margin and padding is that while padding deals with the inner space, margin deals with the outer space to the next outer element.

Comment: Which elements do not have border?

Answer (score 17):

One of the key differences between margin and padding is not mentioned in any of the answers: **clickability and hover detection**

Increasing the padding increases the effective size of the element. Sometimes I have a smallish icon that I don't want to make visibly larger but the user still needs to interact with that icon.  I increase the icon's padding to give it a larger footprint for clicks and hover.  Increasing the icon's margin will not have the same effect.

[An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2226955/185034) to another question on this topic gives an example.

Comment: Most of the top answers refer to padding being "inside" of the element and margins being "outside" of it, which already implies padding contributing to a larger click area. It's not so obvious when you're dealing with a completely transparent box, though...

Answer (score 11):

It is good to know about the differences between `margin` and `padding`. As I know:

- Margin is the *outer space* of an element, while padding is the *inner space* of an element. In other words, margin is the space outside of an element's border, while padding is the space inside of its border.
- You can set `auto` value to margin. However, it's not allowed for padding. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545587/how-to-make-paddingauto-work-in-css).

  **Note:** Use `margin: auto` to center a block element inside its parent horizontally. Also, it's possible to center an element inside a flexbox vertically or horizontally or both, by setting margin to auto. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41129715/4215651).
- Margin can be any float number, but padding must not be negative.
- When you style an element, padding will be styled also; but not margin. Margin gets the parent element's style. For example, when you set the `background-color` property to black, its inner space (i.e. padding) will be black, but not its outer space (i.e. margin).

Answer (score 9):

margin = space around (outside) the element from border outwards.

padding = space around (inside) the element from text to border.

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/robx/GaMpq/

Answer (score 4):

*Margin* is space outside the box; *padding* is space inside the box. It's hard to see the difference with a white fill, but with a colored fill you can see it fine.

Answer (score 3):

Margin and padding are both types of padding really....One (margin) goes outside of the elements border to distance it from other elements and the other (padding) goes outside of the elements content to distance the content from the elements border.

Answer (score 3):

Self Explanatory Image

```
L - Left, R- Right and T - Top, B - Bottom
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Padding is calculated between content and border.
Margin is calculated outside the border.[image: CSS Box Model]

Answer (score 2):

Padding allows the developer to maintain space between the text and it's enclosing element. Margin is the space that the element maintains with another element of the parent DOM.

See example:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UT-8">
    <title>Pseudo Elements</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{font-family:Arial; font-size:16px; background-color:#f8e6ae; color:#888;}
        .page
        {
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 10px 30px 50px 50px;
            margin:30px 100px 30px 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        Notice the distance between the top and this text. Then compare it with the distance between the bottom border and the this text. 
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Margin** is a property in CSS that is used to create spaces around the elements, outside of the border. The programmer can set the margin for top, right, bottom and left. In other words, he can set those values using margin-top, margin-right, margin-bottom and margin-left.

The **Margin** values can be of the following types.

First, auto allows the browser to calculate the margin. Moreover, length denotes a margin in px, pt or cm, while % helps to describe a margin as a percentage relative to the width of the containing element. Finally, inherit denotes that the margin has to inherit from the parent element.

**Padding** is a property in CSS that helps to create space around an element inside the border. The programmer can set the padding for top, right, bottom and left.  In other words, he can set those values using padding-top, padding-right, padding-bottom and padding-left.

The **Padding**  values can be of the following types.

The length describes padding in px, pt or cm, while % denotes padding as a percentage relative to the width of the containing element. Finally, inherit describes that the padding should be inherited from the parent element.

```css
 div.special {
          width:200px; 
          border-style: solid; 
          border-width:thin; 
          border-color:#000;
          margin:30px 20px 10px 25px;
}     
div.special2 {
          width:200px;
          border-style: solid;
          border-width:thin;
          border-color:#000;
          padding:30px 20px 10px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="special">
             Hello its margin test 
</div>
<div class="special2">
            Hello its padding test
</div>
```

**Difference Between Margin and Padding**

**Margin** is a CSS property that is used to create space around the element outside the defined border, while the **padding** is a CSS property that is used to create space around the element, inside the defined border. Thus, this explains the main difference between margin and padding.

**Values**
Furthermore, the values of margin can be auto, length, % or inherit, whereas the values of padding can be length, % or inherit type. Hence, this is another difference between margin and padding.

In brief, **margin and padding** are two properties in CSS that allows styling the web pages. It is not possible to assign negative values for those properties. The main difference between margin and padding is that margin helps to create space around the element outside the border, while padding helps to create space around the element inside the border.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a background color on a block div with width and height. You'll see that padding increases the size of the element, whereas margin just moves it within the flow of the document.

Margin is specifically for shifting the element around.

Answer (score 0):

Padding is the space between nearest components on the web page and margin is the space from the margin of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of margin and padding comes from google's developer tool in the image attached[image]

In Simple words, a margin is the space around an element and padding means the space between an element and the content inside that element.
Both these two are used to create gaps but in different ways.

**Using Margin to create gap:**

In creating gap margin pushes the adjacent elements away

**Using Padding to create gap:**

Using padding to create gap either grows the element's size or shrinks the content inside

**Why is it important to know the difference?**

It is important to know the difference so you could know when to use either of them and use them appropriately.

It is also worthy of note that margins and padding come handy when designing a website's layout, as margin specifies whether an element will move up or down, left or right while padding specifies how an element will look and sit inside its container.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out this link where you can see how paddings and margins works in CSS.
[image]
https://raw.githack.com/sushantbramhacharya/WebTechnology_LEC/main/margin/index.html

Answer (score -1):

There is one important difference:

Margin- is on the outside of the element i.e. one will apply the whitespace shift "after" the element begins.
Padding- is on the inside, the other will apply the whitespace "before" the element begins.

Answer (score -1):

Margin is applied to the outside of you element hence effecting how far your element is away from other elements.

Padding is applied to the inside of your element hence effecting how far your element's content is away from the border.

Also, using margin will not affect your element's dimensions whereas padding will make your elements dimensions (set height + padding) so for example if you have a 100x100px div with a 5 px padding, your div will actually be 105x105px

Comment: did you notice this answer has already been given? - and with an added and appropriate emphasis?

Answer (score -1):

Basically, the difference between padding and margin come in terms of the background. Padding will decide the space between content, while margin decide the outside edge of elements!

Answer (score -1):

One thing I just noticed but none of above answers mentioned.  If I have a dynamically created DOM element which is initialized with empty inner html content, it's a good practice to use margin instead of padding if you don't want this empty element occupy any space except its content is created.

Answer (score -7):

Padding is the space between you content and the border. Where as Margin is the space between **the** border and the other element.

Comment: Margins are not that simple, and this doesn't say anything that a dozen pervious answers haven't already said.

Comment: You just repeated previous answers.