# ScrollView with RelativeLayout dont scroll to end

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a ScrollView in android, inside it i have a RelativeLayout, my problem its the scroll doesnt go to the end and i cant see the last TextView.

This is the XML

```
<!-- Main layout -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TabOrderActivity$OrderDetailFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/fondodroid2"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue_gg"
        android:paddingTop="5dip">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/orderDetail"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:text="Nº"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/file"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            style="@style/orderHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.16"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:text="numero de orden" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/policyHolderLabel"
                    style="@style/orderHeader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/customer"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/policyHolder"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/policyHolderLabel"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cityLabel"
                    style="@style/orderHeader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/city"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/policyHolder"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/city"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cityLabel"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cityLabel" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/provinceLabel"
                    style="@style/orderHeader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/province"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/city"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/province"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/provinceLabel"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/provinceLabel" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/addressLabel"
                    style="@style/orderHeader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/address"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/province"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/address"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addressLabel"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addressLabel" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/zipCode"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addressLabel"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/address"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/phonesLabel"
                    style="@style/orderHeader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/phones"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/zipCode"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/phone1"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/phonesLabel"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/phonesLabel" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/descriptionLabel"
                    style="@style/orderHeader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/description"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/phonesLabel"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/descriptionLabel"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/descriptionLabel"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/coverageLabel"
                    style="@style/orderHeader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Cobertura"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/coverage"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/coverageLabel"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/coverageLabel"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />


            </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to set a LinearLayout inside scrollview and the linearlayout contains the relative but i got the same result.

Whats wrong?

Comment: Use android:layout_height="wrap_content" in initial LinearLayout

Comment: Can't you make this layout with `LinearLayout` with `orientation` property at `vertical`? It's really hard to read!

Comment: @Akagami LinearLayout generate more tree nodes in XML layout and the inflate process its more slow, i need performance. Thanks for the suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the margins to paddings:

```
<RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingTop="20dp"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       android:paddingRight="10dp">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Because you are giving a `marginTop` and then the `ScrollView` won't scroll to the last `20dip` space because the `RelativeLayout` isn't on the proper place it should be. I don't know how to explain it better, sorry! In other words, what you want is to have an inside space between your View and the borders and not an outside space...

Comment: Ok, i think i understand. Thanks, in few minutes i set your aswner as correct.

Comment: @colymore I just made a quick search to find a good explanation. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5958735/3465623