# Bootstrap columns padding on left and right - can i use margin instead?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building my first site with bootstrap (3.3.4) and the columns like for example "col-md-#" have a 15px padding on the left and right side.

Can I replace this padding with margin without getting problems later?

The reason is that i have many boxes with colored background (color or image) and with padding i have no visible space between the boxes when they have a colored background. I don't understand why they use padding and i think there must be a good reason for not using margin(?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better practice **not** to modify core Bootstrap code.

If your only concern is having visible space when the columns have a background color, you can utilize [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-clip) and use `background-clip: content-box;` (on the column) to restrain the background painting area to the content box only. Browser [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) isn't much of a concern either.

Comment: I think this is the best solution for me so far because i don't like to use too much DIVs.

Answer (score 5):

Because col-* is only for construct your grids. If, then, you want to personalize what it's in you grid, you have to add a new block in it, and work with this block instead of the grid.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="greenBlock"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="yellowBlock"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 greenBlock"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 yellowBlock"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this helpful article on the Bootstrap grid, and that will help to explain why padding is used for the gutter:
http://blog.codeply.com/2016/04/06/how-the-bootstrap-grid-really-works

As @thibault-henry explained, you'll want to use a container for your content inside the columnns...

Example: http://codeply.com/go/BCmjjlnrg0

Answer (score 0):

As we know, the box-model does not include the margins into the width of the div. So the margins bleed outside the div.

That is the reason, you can not replace padding:15px with margin. Bootstrap by default uses the following box-model css property.

box-sizing: border-box;

But still if you want to have space between 2 boxes then there is a method.

wrapping the child div with a col-xs-12 and adding the background color to it.

```css
.a {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.b {
    background-color: red;
}

.c {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 a">
    
    <div class="col-xs-6 ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 b">
        Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World 
    </div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 c">
        Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World
    </div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Check my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/5er0wq7z/) link to understand it clearly.