# how can you make another element that's orientated on one that already exists?

Tags: html, css

I've got a page with an element [solid border] and I want to add another smaller element to that [dotted border] with a padding of 5px, now I don't know if it's somehow margin-right:5px or padding-right 5px

[image]

Comment: Please provide the CSS and HTML you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It's margin. You need to understand that `padding` - it's inside margin, and `margin` - it's outside margin. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding) answer to understand it!

[image]