# Android frame layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_msg_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >



            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/messages" />

            <View

                android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            style="@style/HeaderText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:text="@string/header_message" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/notifications" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/HeaderText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:text="@string/header_notification" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The view looks likes this:
[image]

The red circle appears to be trimmed. I need the full circle. The center of the circle should be the left top corner of message icon. What changes should i make in the code so that i can get the desired results

Comment: Try removing the margins for that view. How do you define your circle? I mean the drawable.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#FC1933" android:endColor="#FC1933"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>

Comment: wasyl is right. you should remove margin and add padding instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding

Comment: did that but center is not aligning with the left top corner of message icon

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define negative margins in your view:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
```

So left and top part of the circle are already outside `FrameLayout`. One thing that you could do is to add `android:padding="10dp"` attribute to your `FrameLayout`, giving the image more space on the left and top (you can also add this padding only on top and left side, using `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` attributes

Comment: Then probably the most outer layout is constraining your views. Why not decrease the circle size from `30dp` to ~`10dp`, for example?

Comment: did that but center is not aligning with the left top corner of message icon