# javascript/jquery print method setting page margin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, margin

I have a function to print my page as follows:

```
$("#btn_print").click(function () {

    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printdiv');
    var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');

    newWin.document.open();
    newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()" style="font-family:consolas;@page { size:8.5in 11in; margin: 3cm };" >' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</body></html>');

    newWin.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () {
        newWin.close();
    }, 10);

});
```

I need **3cm** margin space on all sides I mean `Top,Right, Bottom and Left`.

What I doing is above as you can see:

```
@page { 
    size: 8.5in 11in;
    margin: 3cm;
};
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your `<style>`:

```
body {
    margin-top: 3cm;
    margin-bottom: 3cm;
    margin-right: 3cm;
    margin-left: 3cm;
}
```

Or:

```
body {
    margin: 3cm 3cm 3cm 3cm;
}
```

If the above doesn't work try:

```
body {
    padding: 3cm 3cm 3cm 3cm !important;
}
```

Comment: it not working for me buddy. margin-left , margin-right working. But top, bottom not working!!

Comment: printdiv is what I rendered in my page and using print method it prints to another window. So I must add style to that not to my printdiv.

Comment: @Santhucool try using `padding` or `padding-top` `padding-bottom`.

Comment: @Santhucool check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding

Comment: thanks for your valuable links. But sadly I tried padding also nothing got changed!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95446/discussion-between-santhucool-and-leo).