# Removing gap without affecting styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so in a previous post I asked how to remove a gap so that the body takes up the entire height of the browser window. This was solved using:

```
margin: 0;
```

However, I need (or the only way I know to) style my text using margins. As soon as I apply something like

```
margin-top: 50px;
```

the body doesn't fit the 100% height of the browser. I know all of the contents of the div have to use margin 0 in order for it work, but how am I supposed to style things using a margin.

Are there any other ways I can make the body 100% of the browser height?

https://jsfiddle.net/fveb8wsu/

Comment: remove the margin and add `padding-top: 50px` to `#content-mid` instead?

Comment: you're applying margins to entire divs. you should think about putting your text inside a <p> element, and adding your text styling to those.

Comment: Alternatively, add `display: inline-block;` to `#content-mid`

Comment: for text you can use combination of text-indent and padding. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding for more.

Comment: working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fveb8wsu/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Did the trick for me, the `body` has some default paddings. So since the content of the mid was `100vh` + padding this would be greater than `100vh`

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need ? **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/fveb8wsu/5/)**

```css
#content-mid {
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.9;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 750px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
#basics {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 725px;
}
/* Content Text */

#sv_title {
  font-family: BebasNeue;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#sv_sub {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-mid">

  <div id="basics">
    <div id="sv_title">Community Name</div>
    <div id="sv_sub">Your sub title here!</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i agree with everyone, instead of margin use padding, take a look:

```
#content-mid {
background-color: #000000;
opacity: 0.9;
height:100vh;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 200px;
}
#basics { 
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 400px;
width:100%;
padding-top: 50px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/keinchy/5up22vom/1/

-cheers

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is [`collapsing margins`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) between **parent and child element** because parent has no `margin-top` and child has `margin-top: 50px` [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/70/)

So now parent element has `height: 100vh` and `margin-top: 50px` and that is why body doesn't fit the 100% height of the browser.

There are couple options how you could prevent collapsing margins

- Use `display: inline-block` [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/71/)
- Use `display: flex` [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/72/)
- Use `float: left` [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/73/)

Or if you want to keep margin on parent but you don't want height to be more then window height you could use `calc(100vh - marginofchildren)` like this [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/75/)