# CSS margin not set relative to its parent

Tags: html, css

Newbie question alert, please take a look at this example: http://codepen.io/cguo/pen/mVNgvG

The `h1` element's `margin-top` is 60px. Even though the `h1` element is inside the `container` div, the `margin-top` is not set relative to the `container` but to the top of the page.

To achieve what I want, I have to change `h1`'s `margin-top` to `padding-top`.

Why isn't margins set relative to their parents? Is this the standard behavior of margin?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding

Comment: @silviagreen I did read some of the related answers on stackoverflow, but the emphasis that these answers give is `margin is the space outside the border` which is quite easy to understand. But what I don't get why margin is not apply in relation to its parent element in my example.  Is this just how margin works? or did I do something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margins of block level elements fall outside the bounds of their container by default. To make sure they stay inside, you need to make the container a block formatting context root.

There are several ways to do this. One is to give the container a property of overflow:hidden

```
.container
  //existing code
  overflow: hidden
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyoeJO

It's a heady subject, and too complex to explain here, but if you're interested in the mechanics of why elements behave the way they do, I recommend learning about the visual formatting model and block formatting contexts in particular (for starters).

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-block-formatting-contexts-in-css/

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting

Comment: Thanks for the links. I really hope css can be more explicit about these little things which are not commonly mentioned in tutorials

Comment: I agree. The upside is if you study the W3C 2.1 specs, you'll be way ahead of the curve.