# Reduce the distance between tabs and container

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI tabs. How can I reduces the width of the highlighted area(yellow).

[image: jQuery UI Tabs]

```
<script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> </script>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
 <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a><Search</li>
 <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>List</li>
 <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>List</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Probably `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: .ui-tabs{ padding:0px !important; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If #tabs do no have any parents, it is probably the padding of the #tabs container. Try this:

```
#tabs {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

For more details on margin and padding, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the right way -

```
#tabs ul{margin: -1.2em 0em 0em 0em;}
```

Comment: It isn't the best.  If you use margin to cancel out positioning because you don't know why it's positioned that way, before too long you'll have quite a mess on your hands.  Best thing to do is figure out what CSS style is causing you to have more spacing than you want.  A good way to do that (using Chrome) is right click on the space you don't want and select Inspect.  Then see what styling is being applied.  You can edit the values and watch them change on the screen.