# How ignore ConstraintLayout padding in children element

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout

In my App, I want some child view ignore parent view padding.

For Example:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="86dp"
  android:clipToPadding="false"
  android:padding="8dp">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/history_restart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="27dp"
    android:paddingRight="27dp"
    android:text="@string/history_restart_action_text"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Tried it but not working :(

Comment: You're trying to decrease the **margin** to reduce the parent's **padding**.
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding) should help you understand the difference.

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible. Your parent view has a fixed height. Adding the padding means that the greatest height it will assign to its children will be `86dp - 2 * 8dp = 70dp`. Using negative margin will only move your view around. It will not change the height it gets. So will never fill the parent.

You have to give up the padding attribute and instead use margins on every other view inside your layout.