# Why doesn't margin get filled with background color in CSS?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have this simple piece of HTML.

Why doesn't the background color fill the entire `#footer` element's background - specifically, including the margin?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #footer {
      background: #263238;
      margin: 100px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .footer-text {
      margin: 0;
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="footer-text">All Rights Reserved © 2016</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `padding` instead of `margin`. Margin adds external indents. `padding` adds internal.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding. It will help you

Comment: OK. Got It. Thanks all.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should use `padding` instead of `margin` as described by CSS's [Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

- Margin is providing space *beyond* the element's box and therefore **won't** be colored - it's simply space.
- Padding on the other hand provides space around the **inside** of the element's box and is colored and affected by other styles.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>      
  
  <head>
     <style>
        #footer {
           background: #263238;
           padding: 100px;
        }
        .footer-text {
           margin: 0;
           color: #fff;
        }
     </style>
  </head>
    
  <body>
     <div id="footer">
        <div class="footer-text">All Rights Reserved © 2016</div>
     </div>
  </body>   
 
</html>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use color just the top padding/(what I thought would be the margin) not the whole background color of that that div.  Is there away to separate the top into a different color or do you just need a separate div and change the background color of that?

Answer (score 8):

[image: Box model exampe]
This is how the css box model works.
Tha background is applied only to the `padding` and `content` areas, that is why you don't see the background in the margin.
the fix is simple just change the `margin` to be `padding`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `padding`.

If you can use `margin` then it's leave space outside of border and `padding` it's leave space inside border. So it's works perfect for you using `padding`.

```css
 #footer{background: #263238; padding: 100px;}
 .footer-text{margin: 0;color: #fff;}
```

```html
 <div id="footer">
        <div class="footer-text">All Rights Reserved © 2016</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try giving `border: 1px solid transparent` to the parent element of the p tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
           <style>
              #footer{background: #263238;padding: 100px;}
              .footer-text{margin: 0;color: #fff;}
           </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="footer">
                <div class="footer-text">All Rights Reserved © 2016</div>
            </div>
        </body>
   </html>
```

Margin is applied outside the box while padding is applicable inside the box.

Here is an example of margin/padding.

http://www.goer.org/images/html/boxbasic.png

Comment: Please explain why this works. Otherwise it's useless.

Comment: Margin is out side of the box. while Padding is inside the box.

Comment: Put that in your answer. Also that's not a very clear explanation: see : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41283805/1606432

Comment: Updated with an example

Answer (score 0):

**Margin** doesn't get included in the Box-model of your div.

You add **padding** instead of margin. That will get you uniform color in your footer. like this:

```
#footer {
  background: #263238;
  margin:0;
  padding:100px;
}
```

But if you are looking for different color on the outside then you can get this using **border** like this:

```
#footer {
  background: #263238;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:100px solid green;
}
```

Now you can include border in your box-model so it doesn't mess up with your page structure. Do this by defining `box-sizing` for the footer.

```
#footer {
  background: #263238;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:100px solid green;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>      
  
  <head>
     <style>
        #footer {
           background: #263238;
           padding: 100px;
        }
        .footer-text {
           margin: 0;
           color: #fff;
        }
     </style>
  </head>
    
  <body>
     <div id="footer">
        <div class="footer-text">All Rights Reserved © 2016</div>
     </div>
  </body>   
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

give background-colour to the parent of the element (whose margin you want to be coloured)