# How to handle hyperlink in css?

Tags: html, css, web, hyperlink

i have made 5 hyperlinks in html file but i want to give space between them
how should i do it a little help!

thank you!

```
<body>
<div class="back">

    <div class="image">
        <img src="comp.jpg" alt="background image" style="width:100%; height:100%">

    </div>
    <h3 class="name" style="color: #d9d9d9">
        ASHUTOSH KUMAR SINGH
    </h3>

    <div class="link" align="middle">
        <a href="about.html" style="color: white">About</a>
        <a href="contact.html" style="color: white">Contact</a>
        <a href="skill.html" style="color: white">Skills</a>
        <a href="mywork.html" style="color: white">My Work</a>
        <a href="blog" style="color: white">Blog</a>

    </div>
<div class="myimg" align="middle">
    <div class="circle" align="middle">

    </div>
    <img src="ashu.jpg" class="myimage" style="height: 300px; width:300px";>

</div>
 </div>
```

this is my css file: in the code below i have made a class of link in which i
cascaded it. i want to give some equal space between them so that it look neat.

```
html,body{
    margin:0;
}

div.link{
font-size: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    /*text-space: 100;*/
    margin-top:500px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
.back{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
margin: 0;
 }

.image{
    position: fixed;

}
.myimg{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left: 500px;
}
.myimage{

    border: 2px solid rgba(114, 114, 114, 0.55);
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.circle{
    border: 2px ;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
.name{
    position: fixed;
    margin-top:420px;
    margin-left: 530px;
}
```

Comment: Please reproduce what you have done so far in a fiddle or so..

Comment: i want to give spacing between several links help out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most easiest way you're looking for is:

```
.link a {margin-right:10px;}
```

the only problem with this is that all link elements get now a margin-right, from the first to the last one.
if you want to exclude the last element to have no margin right, add an additonal:

```
.link a:last-child{margin-right:0px;}
```

remember that in css you can perfectly nest css selectors

```
html body .back .link a{some-css-rule}
```

by the way, the more specific a selector is, the more important it will be when the browser analyses them)

```
<div class="some_class" id="some_id" style="color:grey;">sometext</div>

#some_id{color:black;}
.some_class{color:blue;}
div {color:green;}
```

the color will be **grey**, because **inline selectors have more weight than selectors with ID, which have more weight than selectors with classes**, which have more weight than selectors with html containers.
This is called CSS specifity
[CSS-specifity calculator by keegan.st](https://specificity.keegan.st/)

[CSS specifity explained by css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid custom CSS-Styles in your HTML-File and include them in your CSS-File. You can use `padding` or `margin` in your CSS-File, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding) for the difference.

**YourHTMLfile.html**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="YourStyleFile.css">
</head>

<body>

  ...

  <div class="link" align="middle">
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      <a href="skill.html">Skills</a>
      <a href="mywork.html">My Work</a>
      <a href="blog">Blog</a>
  </div>

</body>
```

**YourStyleFile.css**

```
.link a {
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
}
```

**EDIT:** make sure to create a CSS-File and add it to your `<head>` section of your HTML-File. They both have to be in the same directory. Another reason why my code may not work for you is that maybe you have another CSS-File which overrides the `.link` class.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a div and style the div with `word-spacing: 10px;` :)