# set margin around child div when parent's width is set using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The site I am working on: https://tricycle-203819.appspot.com/
I would like to replicate the effect on this site where there's multiple sections, and the child divs have margins around the sections: https://www.newyorker.com/

On my site, the div `container-spice`'s width and margin to the left and right is set using javascript on load, and on window size. I would like the children of `left-container`, which is a child of `container-spice`, to have a margin on the right that is of some constant pixel.

Changing the `padding-right` and `margin-right` property of `left-container` do not achieve this effect. I would like to avoid changing the properties of the children of `left-container` if possible, since they will be reused elsewhere.

Comment: Is what you're trying to achieve, essentially a gap between the children of `left-container` and `right-container`?

Comment: @NikkiMather yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `margin-right` on `left-container` *doesn't work* is because the `right-container` won't respect the margin, since it has a position of fixed. You can however add a `padding-right` to `left-container` to achieve your desired affect of creating a gap between the two containers.

Comment: hmm interesting now it works on the left. suppose i wanted a padding on the left side of the right container as well, doing padding-left: 20px does not work. because it's fixed likeyou said?

Comment: No. You need to understand what margin and padding do and how they differ to understand exactly why it isn't working as you expect it to. Please see this link as it should help you make sense of why it's not 'working' as you expect -- if you're still unsure feel free to ask and I'll try and help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding