# Spacing between Material Buttons

Tags: css, angular-material

I have two material buttons in my angular application right next to each other.  I want to add a little bit of padding between them.  But when I add add `padding-right` to the left button, I end up going from this:

```
|  button  ||  button  |
```

To this:

```
|  button         ||  button  |
```

But what I want is this:

```
|  button  |       |  button  |
```

Comment: To add space between two button, add `margin-right: 10px` to first button. But this is only good if you have two button adjacent to each other. Please use this style with a custom CSS class.

Comment: Margin is the space beyond an element's border and other elements while padding is the space between the element's border and it's in inner content. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding

Answer (score 6):

As @nitin9nair comment, what you need is the margin property, in a style attribute or in a CSS class definition:

```
<button style="margin-right:20px">Button 1</button> <button>Button 2</button>
```

If you use flex-layout, you can use the fxLayoutGap directive too.

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="10px grid"><button>Button 1</button> <button>Button 2</button>
```

More info: [https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayoutGap-API][1]

Answer (score 3):

You could also write a css selector, which adds margin to siblings. So this will not apply to the first button, but all following buttons. In this case the mat-raised-button. Just adjust the css selector for the elements where you want to have spacing.

```
.mdc-button ~ .mdc-button {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> **
>
> There are many ways to solve this. please see below some of my
>   observations.
>    - you can add &nbsp ; (non-breaking space) in between both the material buttons.
>
> - < button type="button">Button 1< /button> &nbsp ; &nbsp ; < button type="button">Button 2< /button>
> - second way is you can add the style margin-right:10px to button 1. don't give padding as your given instruction you are giving the
>     padding (padding is for inside spacing to border.) you have to give the
>     margin-right spacing which is spacing beyond the borders.
>
> **