# What is the difference between marginLeft, paddingLeft and marginRight and paddingRight in react-native

Tags: css, react-native

I have set paddingLeft and marginLeft for an image text. Both works in a same way. What is the exact difference for this?

Answer (score -1):

Essentially margin is added to the outside of your element, padding is internal.
So if you give a background color to the text, adding padding will added colored space, while margin will add blank space.

[Difference between margin and padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding)