# How to add margin within input tag

Tags: html, css

How can margin be put within an `<input type="text">` tag. An Example of this is Google's search bar, where there is room between the input border and the text that the user is typing into the bar.

Just in case you wanted to see some code:

```html
<input type=text placeholder=searchHere style=text-align:left
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2189462/3168859),

> Margin is on the outside of block elements while padding is on the
>   inside.

You should set the CSS property `padding` for creating this effect.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="searchHere" style="text-align:left;padding-left:15px;"/>
```

Read more about the differences between `margin` and `padding` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding).

Comment: I wasn't able to back then, it required me to delay for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `padding`.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="searchHere" style="text-align:left; padding:10px;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

that's not `margin` that does the effect you want. it's `padding` so something like this

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Here" style="padding: 10px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

With some effect, just for fun

```
input style="padding: 4px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;"
```