# How to make <a> href tag only clickable on actual content?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a header with a fixed title, horizontally and vertically centred. With a home icon that acts as a link.

The problem is that link is clickable on everything left of the Home icon.

I have tried to replicate the problem in this codepen;

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
}

#header {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(171, 228, 250);
  height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
}

#homeIcon {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 30vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

#headerTitle {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 5vh;
  color: #2d2d2d;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <a href="">
    <img id="homeIcon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/846/846551.svg" alt="homeicon" />
  </a>
  <h1 id="headerTitle"> title </h1>

</div>
```

Is there a way to have the link only on the content of the img tag?

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS you are specifying the `homeIcon` has a `padding-left` of `30vw`.  If you change this to `margin-left` instead, it will no longer be clickable.  This is because `padding` is included inside your element, while `margin` is outside.  See https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp.

Answer (score 0):

The css is your problem: you can solve it by changing `padding-left: 30vw;` to `margin-left: 30vw;`

This answer may be useful background reading: [Difference between margin and padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding)