# How can I remove horizontal scrollbar in wordpress with css?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have tried this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;    
}
```

There is a small white column to the right side of the page, so there is a horizontal scrollbar. I want to see all the contents in a page so that I do not need horizontal scrollbar and I do not need that extra small white column of a page. How can I remove horizontal scrollbar in wordpress with css or what should I do to remove that horizontal scrollbar and that extra small white column?

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow-x: hidden;` to your css to hide the horizontal scroll.

Comment: Going to reference you to this good answer for that :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/5958724/4101210

Comment: Is there any other way without html {overflow-x: hidden;}?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to make it more difficult?

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%; 
    overflow-x: hidden;   
}
```

Comment: Already stated in other answer from 2020.