# Why border-radius is not working with padding?

Tags: html, css, padding, margin, border-radius

I have problem in **CSS**. I want to design a login page like picture below.

[image]

I used **padding-top** for create space between picture and top border of the page. But when I do this, the **border-radius** of picture is not working for all corners! It is not working for border top right and left! I do not know why this happen!

**HTML**

```
<img src="img/avatar-01.jpg" alt="" class="Image">
```

**CSS**

```
.Image {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
```

Here is output with padding: [image]

However if I use **margin-top** it works correctly!!

**CSS**

```
.Image {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 125px auto 10px 612px;
}
```

Here is output with margin: [image]

Why this happen? Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Please, provide HTML or create a new fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net) and provide a link to it.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958699/difference-between-margin-and-padding)

Comment: @Sfili_81 My question is not about differences between margin and padding!!! I know the differences!! But I do not know why border-radius not working for 2 corners with padding!

Comment: padding is working but because of padding top its showing on top give a color or border to element then you can see what exactly is happening.

Comment: Use the browser developer tools to inspect the element. There you will see every gap and how its calculated.

Answer (score 1):

It works as it should but because padding is calculated inside the element, it adds to the size of your `.Image` from the top (since you are **adding** the padding). That's why you need to use `margin-top`, margin is rendered outside the element and does not change the actual size of it.

There's also an attribute called `box-sizing` which could be set to in cases like these to `border-box` which makes padding to not stretch the element but only if element is smaller than all paddings combined.

You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model).